# how to use opengl in wince 6.0 r2?

Tags: opengl, windows-ce

I am very new in opengl.i want to use opengl in wince 6.0 r2.is wince supports opengl?if yes can anyone give me pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS doesn't provide OpenGL on WinCE.   Some OEMs may add it into their CE-based device, but its not from MS.  I've seen 3rd party solutions like OpenGL ES from [Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/developers/resources/opengles/#timplementations).